# db2 config file update without db connection

Tags: error-handling, db2

I am using db2 9.7 database and I cannot connect to it since I am getting an error of db2tsm.dll reason code 1. I restored most backup to another database and compared the config files. In the corrupted database the logarchmeth1 is set to TSM.

Is it possible to change that parameter without being connected to the database??

thank you

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can change that parameter.

```
db2 update db cfg for SAMPLE using logarchmeth1 DISK:/tmp
```

In the previous example, you are going to keep the archive logs, but instead of using TSM, you will be using a file system in disk for them.

Make sure that logarchmeth2 is empty, or something that do not use TSM.

If you change the logarchmeth1 (and logarchmeth2) to OFF, you will change the logs to circular mode, then you should issue a full backup and your recovery strategy will be changed (no Point-in-time recoveries).

Finally, if the database is in crash recovery and it needs the archive logs, you will have to extract them from TSM, and put them in disk, with the same directory structure of the log chains (SAMPLE/db2inst1/NODE0000/C0000000). However, I think your database is not in crash recovery, only that it cannot archive logs via TSM. With the proposed solution, logs will be shipped to disk instead of tape, but remember to store them in other place.